# JNI First value of jintArray incorrect

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

What I'm trying to do is drawing a polygon from Java to a direct 2d c++ window. I have 2 arrays containing the x-points and y-points of the polygon. When printing the array the array shows correct except for the first element in both arrays.

On the Java side:

```
Polygon fillPoly = new Polygon(new int[] {200, 250, 300}, new int[] {400, 350, 400}, 3);
// 200, 400 | 250, 350 | 300, 400

g.fillPolygon(fillPoly);

//...

public void fillPolygon(final Polygon polygon) {
    fillPoly(polygon.xpoints, polygon.ypoints, polygon.npoints);
}

private native void fillPoly(final int[] xpoints, final int ypoints[], final int numPoints);
```

But the output on the `data` string are things like:

```
start: 693635144, 693771992 | Path: 693635144, 693771992 - 0, 0 - 718079568, 693635144 - | numPoints: 3
start: 35, 29 | Path: 35, 29 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 35, 32 | Path: 35, 32 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 35, -1437401059 | Path: 35, -1437401059 - 250, 4 - 300, 2949120 - | numPoints: 3
start: 35, 39573896 | Path: 35, 39573896 - 250, 1 - 300, 0 - | numPoints: 3
start: 47, 44 | Path: 47, 44 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 53, 47 | Path: 53, 47 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 53, 39589128 | Path: 53, 39589128 - 250, 1 - 300, 0 - | numPoints: 3
start: 56, 53 | Path: 56, 53 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 56, 50 | Path: 56, 50 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 39591176, 39591176 | Path: 39591176, 39591176 - 1, 12 - 99607256, 0 - | numPoints: 3
start: 71, 59 | Path: 71, 59 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
start: 71, 68 | Path: 71, 68 - 250, 350 - 300, 400 - | numPoints: 3
```

If I provide the points myself it works, but not with the `jintArrays`. How would I correctly retrieve the int values of the `jint*` and create `D2D1::Point2F` from them?

Comment: What are `xpoints` and `ypoints` in the native code? I can see what `xpoint`/`ypoint` and `jxpoints`/`jypoints` are, but I don't see `xpoints`/`ypoints` being declared anywhere.

Comment: I added the header information

Comment: I still don't see `xpoints` and `ypoints` being declared anywhere in the C++ code you've shown.

Comment: I fixed it in the question now, it's because I store the `std::function` in a  `std::vector` which is called between `BeginDraw()` and `EndDraw()` to paint the polygon which has `xpoints` and `ypoints` as parameter. The `xpoints` and `ypoints` are just the `jxpoints` and `jypoints`. My bad. I still don't know how to fix the code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code stores the pointers to jxpoints, jypoints for later use, and releases the Java arrays. No wonder that sometimes these pointers point to data that has randomly changed. You probably need to copy the coordinates to some persistent C++ array, e.g. via `shared_pointer<vector<jint>>`:

```
vector<jint> jxpoints(numPoints);
env->GetIntArrayRegion(xpoint, 0, numPoints, &jxpoints[0]);
```